# Two floating point values do not get added and printed on ESP-WROOM-32

Tags: serial, esp32, float

I have a [Olimex ESP32-PoE](https://www.olimex.com/Products/IoT/ESP32/ESP32-POE/open-source-hardware) board which has a **ESP-WROOM-32**.

I just found out a strange behaviour for printing floating point numbers on the board.

#### Sketch

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  float a=34567891.234;
  float b=2.3456;
  a++;
  Serial.print(a+b, 4);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
}
```

the sketch is extremely simple where I want to add two floating point numbers, one a big and another small to print their addition result upto 4 places.

#### Output

on the serial console in the Arduino IDE

```
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
```

Everytime I increment the `float a` using `a++` i expect it to increment by one and print the result but the output above is completely off.

#### Without Increment

```
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  float a=34567891.234;
  float b=2.3456;
  Serial.print(a+b, 4);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

}
```

#### output

```
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
34567896.0000
```

Same output.

Is this Board specific or is the `Serial.print` not supporting float?

Comment: Try doubles.  34567891.234 needs 35 bits of precision to keep the decimals, but floats only have 23.

Comment: There is a similar question, but that confuses me even more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561393/is-using-increment-operator-on-floats-bad-style

Comment: The thing that confuses me, is that even if the compiler decides to round up both numbers (I remember I had this somewhere, that if you do not specify that the sum is also float, it acts as if they are integers), it would still be 34567895.0000, not 34567896.0000. So I am also at a loss here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in comments and Dave X's answer, floats have a limited
resolution. That resolution is given by the constant `FLT_EPSILON`,
which is the difference between 1 and the smallest float larger than 1.
On any system conformant to IEEE 754, `FLT_EPSILON` is 2<sup>−23</sup>,
or about 1.19e-7. The implication is that, within the interval
[1, 2], the real numbers that can be exactly represented by floats
are the multiples of `FLT_EPSILON`. The resolution, however, degrades as
you consider larger numbers. Within the interval [2, 4] it is twice
as coarse. Within [4, 8], it's four times as coarse and so on:

```
interval     resolution
------------------------------------------
1    – 2     2^-23 ≈ 1.19e-7 (FLT_EPSILON)
2    – 4     2^-22
...
2^23 – 2^24  1
2^24 – 2^25  2
2^25 – 2^26  4
...
```

Your number `a` is just slightly larger than 2<sup>25</sup>. Within this
range, the numerical resolution (aka “ulp”: unit in the last place)
is 4 (last line in the table above). Thus floats in this range can
only represent exact multiples of 4. When you write

```c++
double a=34567891.234;
```

the compiler replaces this by the closest float, which happens to be
34567892. Same thing for b, but in this case the rounding error is tiny
and inconsequential (about -1.1e-7). When you write

```c++
a++;
```

you are replacing `a` with the float that is closest to `a+1`, which
happens to be `a` itself. So the instruction has no effect. When yo do

```c++
Serial.print(a+b, 4);
```

you are computing the float closest to 34567892+2.3456, which is
34567896.

A `double` instead has a resolution `DBL_EPSILON` which is
2<sup>−52</sup>, or about 2.22e-16. This gives you some precision
margin, but be aware that AVR-based Arduinos do not really support
doubles and treat the `double` keyword as a synonym for `float`. This
may only be an issue if you ever have to move your code to a more
traditional Arduino.

Comment: I didn't know about the AVR double-float synonym.  thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try doubles instead of floats.

Your initial value, 34567891.234 needs 35 bits of precision to keep track of the decimals, but floats only have 24 bits pf precision. So to have enough precision to keep track of the difference between `34567891.234` and `34567891.234+1`, you need higher precision storage.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  double a=34567891.234;
  double b=2.3456;
  a++;
  Serial.print(a+b, 4);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
}
```